# How to load a DFS table of DolphinDB into Python client with Orca?

Tags: database, pandas, load, microsoft-distributed-file-system, dolphindb

I am trying to replace pandas with Orca in my project for a better performance. But I don't know How to load data from a DolphinDB DFS table, which I have already created and imported data into on DolphinDB Server.

I load the table in this way in DolphinDB:

```
tb=loadTable("dfs://tickData", "tick1")
```

How to load a DolphinDB DFS table into Python client using Orca?

Answer (score 0):

```
import dolphindb.orca as orca
orca.read_table("dfs://tickData", "tick1")
```